# KVL in the capacitor during transient analysis

Tags: capacitor, kirchhoffs-laws, transient

I can see that this topic has been discussed many times in this site. But I still can't figure out why I am still not getting my correct equation applying the KVL.
Consider a circuit as shown:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC7L9T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I figured out that the capacitor charges to 6V at t<0. For t>0, there is discharging of the capacitor through the resistor and inductor. The direction of discharge is as shown by the red arrow. So I applied the KVL in this loop and the equation is

[image].

I am writing -ve value for the instantaneous voltage across the capacitor because the current I have supposed is discharging the capacitor. But my teacher told the equation I wrote was wrong but couldn't convince me why exactly I was wrong. I don't have any kind of problem with the further math involved in finding the expression for transient current. I just want to know what is the correct equation and why it is correct.

Comment: Your units don't work out right, for one thing... 1F is still 1F, not just 1.

Comment: Its 1/C, so I just didn't write that. Also I haven't mentioned the 1 ohm in resistor.

Comment: Seems right to me..

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Perhaps your professor expected you to use the same current sign convention as for the charging capacitor.

Comment: @Chu,does that change the final equation for current?

Comment: It changes the **sign** of the discharging current - I guess for accuracy vis-a-vis the complete expression for capacitor current, this should be a negative current if the charging current is declared as positive.